# Installing a JNDI datasource for Oracle 11g in Tomcat

Tags: database, tomcat, jndi

I'm on Windows XP, using Tomcat 6 ( I can't upgrade to 7 until the end of the month ).

I've been trying to implement a JNDI database resource to Oracle 11g without success.

A number of other applications on my computer connect just fine with the same database credentials.  I made a test JSP using straight up JDBC and put it into Tomcat.  It connects just fine too.

**I modified a section of my conf/server.xml like this:**

```
 <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
     <Resource name="jdbc/mydb"
               auth="Container"
               type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
               factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
               url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@apollo.abc.acme.com:2222:mydatabase"
               user="joe"
               password="blow"
               maxActive="20"
               maxIdle="30"
               maxWait="-1"/>   

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

**My conf/context.xml:**

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/mydb" name="jdbc/mydb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>


    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

</Context>
```

**My conf/web.xml:**

```
 <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

This is an excerpt from test JSP, it is crapping out with a nullpointer exception right where it goes to get the JNDI resource:

```
Connection conn         = null;
ResultSet result        = null;
Statement stmt          = null;
String nsdtestcount     = null;
InitialContext ctx      = null;
Context envContext      = null;
javax.sql.DataSource ds = null;

try
{

    ctx        = new InitialContext();
    envContext = (Context)ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    ds         = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/mydb");
    conn       = ds.getConnection();      

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(nameJSP + "Failed to connect to the database: " +
    "\n ctx        =  " + ctx         +
    "\n envContext =  " + envContext  +
    "\n ds         =  " + ds          +
    "\n conn       =  " + conn          );

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**An excerpt from my log:**:

```
INFO: Server startup in 675 ms
testJNDI2.jsp: Failed to connect to the database:
 ctx        =  javax.naming.InitialContext@15356d5
 envContext =  org.apache.naming.NamingContext@69d02b
 ds         =  null
 conn       =  null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jsp.testJNDI_jsp._jspService(testJNDI_jsp.java:114)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

**The code at the line in the stack trace:**

```
 at org.apache.jsp.testJNDI_jsp._jspService(testJNDI_jsp.java:114)
   ctx        = new InitialContext();
    envContext = (Context)ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    ds         = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/mydb");
    conn       = ds.getConnection();
```

conn = ds.getConnection(); is line 114

**From my catalina log:**

```
May 1, 2012 4:17:48 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry registerComponent
SEVERE: Null component Catalina:type=DataSource,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/mydb"
```

**The contents of my CATALINA_HOME/lib:**

```
C:\tomcat\lib>ls -l

 annotations-api.jar
 catalina-ant.jar
 catalina-ha.jar
 catalina-tribes.jar
 catalina.jar
 ecj-3.3.1.jar
 el-api.jar
 jasper-el.jar
 jasper.jar
 jsp-api.jar
 log4j-1.2.16.jar
 ojdbc14.jar
 servlet-api.jar
 tomcat-coyote.jar
 tomcat-dbcp.jar
 tomcat-i18n-es.jar
 tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
 tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
 tomcat-juli-adapters.jar
 tomcat-juli.jar

C:\tomcat\lib>
```

**The contents of my JAVA/JDK jre/lib/ext:**

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\jre\lib\ext>ls -l

 activation.jar
 dnsns.jar
 localedata.jar
 log4j-1.2.16.jar
 mail.jar
 nls_charset12.jar
 sunjce_provider.jar
 sunmscapi.jar
 sunpkcs11.jar

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\jre\lib\ext>
```

Any ideas of what I can try?  I would like to make the database resource available to everything running in Tomcat ( it is my dev environment )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the stack trace from the error message? Where did you place your JAR file with the JDBC driver?

Comment: Good points, I updated my original post with all of that information.

Comment: Your code is swallowing the stack trace. Modify it to print it out. Also, check the Tomcat logs for error messages setting up the data source.

Comment: Updated the test.jsp to print the stack trace, checked my catalina log.  I modified my original post.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Check the other logs as well - just to be sure. It is pretty clear that Tomcat is failing to create the DataSource. What isn't yet clear is why.

Comment: I checked the other logs.  Those are all of the error messages.

Comment: Time for me to do some more digging in the Tomcat source code. I'd expect there to be other error messages.

Comment: Never add anything into lib/ext unless the installation instructions specifically tell you to do so. It isn't a repository for stuff you don't know what to do with, or a panacea for all class loading ills.

Answer (score 1):

There may well be multiple issues but the first is that you have multiple copies of multiple versions of the Oracle JDBC driver in $CATALINA_HOME/lib and $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext.

Step 1 is to remove all instance of the following JARs apart from $CATALINA_HOME/lib/ojdbc14.jar

- ojdbc14.jar
- ojdbc14_g.jar
- ojdbc14dms.jar
- ojdbc14dms_g.jar
- classes12.jar
- classes12.zip
- classes12dms.jar

While you are at it, remove $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar as well.

Step 2 is that maxIdle > maxActive does not make any sense. You want maxActive >= maxIdle.

Comment: Done.  Still no joy.  I updated my post with more error information and new directory listings.

Comment: Nope. You still have multiple copies of ojdbc14.jar

Comment: I yanked the ojdbc14.jar from my tomcat/lib.  No change in error messages.

Comment: That isn't what I suggested that you try. It should work but the standard place for that JAR is a single copy in $CATALINA_HOME/lib.

Comment: I switched location of the ojdbc14.jar to tomcat/lib.  It didn't help. I have another test.jsp that uses the straight jdbc it finds the driver, connects, etc just fine.   Does Tomcat need extra jars for JNDI?

Comment: No extra JARs required. It works out of the box. As I said elsewhere, I need to dig into why you aren't seeing an error message.

Comment: I am ( see my original post ), just not a helpful one.  Aside from the nullpointer exception, in my catalina log I get:
SEVERE: Null component Catalina:type=DataSource,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/mydb"

Comment: That error message is coming from JMX registration. I'd expect to see another one when the Pool cannot be created. It could be that it is being swallowed due a Tomcat bug. That is what I need to look into.

Comment: You should also move the log4j JAR file. It has no business being there. It isn't an extension.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in this example on the [tomcat site](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Oracle_8i,_9i_&_10g), I believe "user" should be "username" in your Resource definition.