# Issue configuring Tomcat 7 JDNI datasource in Context file

Tags: java, spring, datasource, tomcat7, jndi

This is the exception that I get:

`Error creating bean with name 'jndiDataSource' defined in class path resource [spring/database.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [connection_pool] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [connection_pool]`

This is my datasource bean:

```
<bean id="jndiDataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="connection_pool" />
</bean>
```

This is my context file `MyApp##1.0.2.xml` that I dropped into `tomcat7/conf/Catalina/localhost`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="path\to\war\my-app-1.0.2.war"
    antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >

<Resource name="connection_pool" 
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username="username" password="password" 
            auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" />

</Context>
```

Does anyone have any ideas of why this is not working?

Comment: Just guessing here, but have you tried it without the underscore in the name?

Comment: I just did and it still does not work...

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183321/how-to-use-jndi-datasource-provided-by-tomcat-in-spring

Answer (score 0):

try this instead, it should provide the correct configuration:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myDataSource" jndi-name="java:connection_pool" />
```