# Unable to use JNDI DataSource provided by Tomcat in Spring?

Tags: spring, tomcat, tomcat7, jndi, connection-pooling

I want to use JNDI DataSource provided by Tomcat in Spring based application. I use Tomcat 7 pool. Tried to configure as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183321/how-to-use-jndi-datasource-provided-by-tomcat-in-spring).

Configured server.xml of Tomcat:

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="jdbc/ApsuserAtAzistst"
              auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.153.10:1525:AZISTST"
              username="APSUSER"
              password="PASSWORDOFAPSUSER"
              initialSize="1"
              minIdle="1"
              maxIdle="1"
              maxActive="3"
              maxWait="1000"
              validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
              jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport(threshold=1500)"
            />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

created META-INF\context.xml with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/ApsuserAtAzistst"
                  global="jdbc/ApsuserAtAzistst"
                  type="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

and configured applicationContext.xml

```
<beans profile="dev,test,default">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/ApsuserAtAzistst"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

When I run applcation I receive an error:

```
SEVERE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:146)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:119)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:73)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
```

Everything works when I change applicationContext.xml to:

```
<beans profile="dev,test,default">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.153.10:1525:AZISTST"/>
        <property name="username" value="APSUSER"/>
        <property name="password" value="PASSWORDOFAPSUSER"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="3"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
        <property name="jdbcInterceptors"
                  value="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport(threshold=1500)"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

But I want to configure JNDI DataSource in Tomcat and use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason was that, I missed factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory". Right definition of resource must be

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="jdbc/ApsuserAtAzistst"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.153.10:1525:AZISTST"
              username="APSUSER"
              password="PASSWORDOFAPSUSER"
              initialSize="1"
              minIdle="1"
              maxIdle="1"
              maxActive="3"
              maxWait="1000"
              validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
              jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport(threshold=1500)"
            />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```