# How to configure JNDI datasource in Jboss using HikariCP?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jboss, hikaricp

How to configure a JNDI datasource in jboss configuration file using HikariCP I can't find aything in the help contents of Hikari there is only Tomcat configuration .

I have a Spring webb app, I have a datasource defined inside the application and I want to move this to a JNDI datasource.

My datasource definition is:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mydatasource" pool-name="mydatasource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
     <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database</connection-url>
     <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
     <datasource-class>com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource</datasource-class>
     <driver>postgresql</driver>
     <pool>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
     </pool>
     <security>
         <user-name>user</user-name>
         <password>password</password>
     </security>
</datasource>
```

And the driver definition:

```
<driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql.jdbc">
    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

I'm getting this error among others:

> ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
>       ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>       ("data-source" => "mydatasource")
>   ]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>       "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/mydatasource is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql]",
>       "jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/mydatasource is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql]"
>   ]}

So what is the right way to configure this?

**EDIT:**

Following the guide to create the Tomcat resource and using the information provided in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183321/how-to-use-jndi-datasource-provided-by-tomcat-in-spring) I have come to this DataSource definition:

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/mydatasource" pool-name="mydatasource" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databasename</connection-url>
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>username</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <statement>
         <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

I installed the postgresql driver in Jboss and declared it.

And in Spring configuration

```
...
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dataSourceLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSourceTemp = null;
    try {
        dataSourceTemp = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/mydatasource");
    } catch (DataSourceLookupFailureException e) {
        log.error("DataSource not found.");
    }
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setDataSource(dataSourceTemp);
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
}
...
```

This code based on HikariJNDIFactory code,everything seems to work but I think I have to create a properties object with the properties of the connection what properties I have to include in the object?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the configuration for a "pure" Tomcat JNDI DataSource:

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/JNDI-DataSource-Factory-(Tomcat,-etc.)

You might also find this answer Re: Spring + Tomcat + JNDI informative:

[How to use JNDI DataSource provided by Tomcat in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183321/how-to-use-jndi-datasource-provided-by-tomcat-in-spring)

Also recommended is the latest HikariCP 2.0.1.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I have used what you suggested and I have some problems still:
In the Tomcat resource declaration there's a property "factory" that I can't find in Jboss DataSource definition is that property mandatory to construct the DataSource?

I can declare a Datasource in Jboss and retrieve it to the Spring configuration class but the problem is how do I declare the datasource with the class HikariDataSource?

Comment: Does this JBoss example help?  http://genesyslab.info/wiki/index.php/Connection_Pooling

Comment: Thanks the links helped me a lot, but I took a sightly different approach, I create the HikariDataSource Object based on the code on HikariJNDIFactory, I loaded the JNDI DataSource with a Spring Class and put the datasource to a new HikariConfig Object but I still don't know how to build the Properties object for the HikariConfig Constructor.

Comment: @GersonSosa same issue here. I can create a HikariConfig, the jndi datasource and the entitymanager but cant find how to put them all together. In HikariCPConnectionProvider there is a DataSource property but cannot be accessed with spring. when we instanciate the provider it only accepts String from jpaProperties map

Comment: @brettw, the link is not up anymore (seems that they changed the target). Could you repost it?