# Using Hibernate in Spring MVC app on Jboss

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss7.x

I am working on a Spring MVC app using Jboss 7.1.1. Until now, we are using simple database connectivity using JDBC. Like:

```
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
```

Now we decided to use JPA (Hibernate) annotations for database operations. The problem is that I know very little about Hibernate, and I have not much idea from where to start.

Where should I start? I have setup MySQL data source in Jboss. Do I need to configure Hibernate with jboss?

Comment: Can be closed as "too broad". From the official close reasons: _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer_.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to configure spring hibernate for any server. One way I follow is [this](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-session-factory-annotation.jsp). Notice the `spring-config.xml` file in the tutorial. They have created a datasource within the application. If you have the datasource in the server then get it by [JNDI reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9183486/258741) .

Comment: Thanks. Is spring mvc and spring without mvc have different methods to use JPA(hibernate)?