# How to bind a JDBC datasource to JNDI context "java:comp/env/jdbc" when not to use web.xml

Tags: java, spring, jndi, servlet-3.0

How to bind a JDBC datasource to JNDI context `java:comp/env/jdbc` only using code-based approach.

We need to write `resource-ref` in the `web.xml` for binding a dataSource to JNDI local context `java:comp/env/jdbc`.
But I want to use only `org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer` instead of `web.xml`(the old approach).

We know the method `InitialContext#createSubcontext`. But some application servers(e.g. Websphere) do not accept to edit the context `java:comp/env/jdbc/`.

Any solutions?

Versions:

- Spring 4.0.7
- Servlet 3.0

Comment: You've already discovered that some containers don't support it. Therefore there is no answer to this question.

Comment: @sndyuk please accept answer below if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

You could try a full programmatic approach using Spring's SimpleNamingContextBuilder:

```
  SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
  DataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource(...);
  builder.bind("java:comp/env/jdbc/myds", ds); // you control the datasource
  builder.activate();
```

It's mainly there for test-purposes. If you choose to use it then you need to provide your own connection pool (e.g. Apache's Jakarta Commons DBCP).

I once used for testing when I deployed to cloudbees. [see this blogpost](http://mistafry.blogspot.no/2012/11/java-in-cloud.html)

This works in "plain" Tomcat. I don't have a EE server to test with, but you could try it and see what happens (I guess the JNDI binding name has to be unique to the server though).

Answer (score 0):

What is your application server?

See if this helps.

[How to use JNDI DataSource provided by Tomcat in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183321/how-to-use-jndi-datasource-provided-by-tomcat-in-spring)

Comment: I know how to use a datasource in Spring. I want to know how to bind a datasource to `java:comp/env/jdbc/..`.