# Spring autowiring gives null bean for Abstract class

Tags: java, spring, autowired, jdbctemplate, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to Inject(Autowire) JDBCTemplate into my Dao Class which is an "Abstract class", This is not working and as spring is giving null bean for JDBCTemplate.

```
public abstract class SSODaoImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements  SSODao{

    public SSODaoImpl(){

    }
    @Autowired //giving null jdbcTemplate
    public SSODaoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
    super.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    }
}
```

SSODaoImpl is extended my many other DAOs' like the one below

```
@Repository("askBenefitsDAO")
public class AskBenefitsSSODaoImpl extends SSODaoImpl{
}
```

I have created the bean in a file JDBCContext.xml and referenced it in web.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
     <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jndi/hpdb_hrdb"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
<constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name> /WEB-INF/spring/JDBCTemplate/JDBCContext.xml</param-value>       
</context-param>
```

---

Error message from spring while starting the application

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'askBenefitsDAO' defined in file [AskBenefitsSSODaoImpl.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
```

The above setup is working for an "Non Abstract class" set up. Please help me with this and let me know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I'm not sure this is related to the abstract class.  JdbcTemplate takes a `javax.sql.DataSource` in its constructor.  From the xml, the constructor argument refers to dataSource but dataSource is not a `javax.sql.DataSource`.

Comment: @Andrew S I referred the below link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183321/how-to-use-jndi-datasource-provided-by-tomcat-in-spring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the **spring is not directly invoking the constructor of your SSODaoImpl** class, instead the **call of its constructor is happening when Spring is instantiating the AskBenefitsSSODaoImpl class** and hence Spring is unable to bind the jdbcTemplate to your SSODaoImpl class.

You can achieve this my modifying your code to as below:

```
@Repository("askBenefitsDAO")
public class AskBenefitsSSODaoImpl extends SSODaoImpl{
@Autowired 
    public AskBenefitsSSODaoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
    super(jdbcTemplate);
    }

}

public abstract class SSODaoImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements  SSODao{

    public SSODaoImpl(){

    }
    public SSODaoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
    super.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    }
}
```