# Unable to connect to JNDI Datasource from Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource, jboss7.x

I am trying to access Database using DataSource from Spring Boot application. The Jndi Name of my datasource is java:jboss/datasources/Mypool. I am deploying the application as war file in JBoss EAP server.

In pom.xml I have removed the Apache Tomcat AS like the below:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I have added the following lines in application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    jndi-name: java:jboss/datasources/MyPool
```

But when I am trying to access DB from a DAO class, it is throwing the following exception:

```
13:49:56,507 SEVERE [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool] (http-/10.150.60.245:8080-1) Unable to create initial connections of pool.: java.sql.SQLException
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:332) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.31.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.31.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:736) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.31.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:668) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.31.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.31.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.31.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.31.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.31.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.31.jar:]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:394) [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:478) [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:488) [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:498) [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:504) [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    ...
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736) [spring-aop-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671) [spring-aop-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    ...
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:413) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.31.jar:]
    ... 79 more
```

The same code is working when I am accessing the database by Driver Manager and not by DataSource, i.e. when I am having the following lines in my application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    url: testurl
    username: test
    password: test
```

So there is no problem in the code. Please help.

Comment: You are using JNDI so then use it. You are specifying the `driver-class-name` don't as that indicates you don't use JNDI but want to use the regular tomcat connection pool. Basically they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I get the same error when I do not use driver-class-name.

Comment: I doubt it it the same exception. I fit is there is something else triggering the registration of that class as the driver.

Comment: Also removing tomcat doesn't mean you are removing the connection pool. Also you shouldn't need to when specifying the `jndi-name`. What you should do is follow the proper instructions on how to build a `war` (i.e. make those dependencies scoped provided). Could you specify which Spring Boot version you are using

Comment: I am using spring boot 1.5.13.RELEASE

Comment: I am getting the following warning when removing driver-class-name from application.yml - Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null. Also Updated my original post with the full exception stack trace I am getting in that case.

Comment: That shouldn't matter as that is information only...

Comment: Did you try this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29364912/1766417

Comment: Another update, I as also able to access database if I do not use spring boot, but access it using plain JDBC DataSource. Now I am sure that I am doing something wrong in spring boot configuration and the datasource is configured properly at the server.

Comment: No I have not tried the andwer at  stackoverflow.com/a/29364912/1766417. I can try but it is the way we would do using spring. Using spring boot, I think we can specify it in application.properties or application.yml and that is not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609355/unable-to-build-spring-boot-project-having-datasource-lookup-from-jndi#51609455